# Python Deep Learning Keras: Wrong number of dimensions: expected 3, got 2 with shape

Tags: python, keras

I am new to Keras, a deep learning library and need your help. The model is built without errors, but has the following issue when calling model.fit(X, y):

```
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function with name "~/machine_learning2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/theano_backend.py:380"  
at index 0(0-based)', 'Wrong number of dimensions: expected 3, got 2 with shape (16, 40).')
```

This is similar as this one https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/815
My y train matrix is a matrix with multiple rows and one column.

One solution mentioned about converting y to 3d tensor with binary one-hot coding. Is there an example of this?

Comment: Could you please provide the architecture of your network?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
from keras.utils import np_utils
np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, n_classes)
```

for one hot encoding, where y_train is a train class vector and n_classes - total number of a classes,

However, based on that the error description mentions (16, 40), rather than a (Nx1), I suspect you might have an issue with your X as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>b=np.arange(640)
>b.reshape(16,40).shape
 (16, 40)
>c=b.reshape(1,16,40)
>c.shape
 (1, 16, 40)
```